# Как правильно прерывать поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня код, в котором работают два параллельных потока, и если они выполняются больше секунды, то надо отменить выполнение обоих потоков.
Я хочу использовать для этого конструкцию `thread01.isInterrunt(); thread02.isInterrunt();` , но проблема заключается в то что я не понимаю когда именно их вызывать (то есть где).

Вот код:

```
public class CounterOfSpace {
    private int counterOfSpaces;
    private int counterOfWords;
    private String text;
    private Thread thread01;
    private Thread thread02;

    public CounterOfSpace(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    void startAll() {
        System.out.println("Start program");

        calcWords();
        calcSpaces();
        thread01.start();
        thread02.start();
        try {
            thread01.join();
            thread02.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finish program");
    }

    private void calcSpaces() {
        thread01 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text.length() == 0) return;
                for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                    if (c == ' ') {
                        counterOfSpaces++;
                        System.out.println("counterOfSpaces "+counterOfSpaces);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void calcWords() {
        thread02 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text.length() == 0) return;
                String[] words = text.split(" ");
                for (String word : words) {
                    if (!word.equals(" ")) {
                        counterOfWords++;
                        System.out.println("counterOfWords "+counterOfWords);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Вот где то в методе `startAll()`, я должен вызвать `isInterrunt()`, с условием если от момента их запука, прошло времени больше 1 сек. Но где точно, ведь потока 2, и надо прирвать оба, как только время выйдет за границы, а не просто отказаться от использования результата выполнения, если время, больше одной секунды. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне именно остановить выполнение, как только время превысит 1 сек?

Comment: Как вариант, сделать ещё поток, который следит за временем

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman >>>опишите задачу, а не решение<<< в смысле? а что разве я не описал? поясните пожалуйста

Comment: вы описали решение - два потока выполняются и т.д. это решение, а не задача.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman нет это контекст задачи, а сама задача в то что-бы их остановить при условии... А остановки у меня нигде нет. Где у меня в коде остановка потоков?

Comment: у вас ведь потоки не ради потоков? а для выполнения какой-то задачи. так вот, часто задачу можно решить разными способами.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Да у меня потоки ради потоков это задание ученическое я только приступил к изучению многопоточности. Это мое первое задание по этой теме.  Поэтому и вопросы глупые...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3); 
Future handler1 = executor.submit(thread01);
Future handler2 = executor.submit(thread02);
executor.schedule(() -> {
    handler1.cancel(true);
    handler2.cancel(true);
}, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Без лямбды

```
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler1.cancel(true);
        handler2.cancel(true);
    }
}, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А как бы это выглядело без лямбда выражения?

Comment: добавил без лямбды

Comment: Ой извините а мне же задали с isInterrunt() это сделать... Это же не тоже самое?

Comment: метод `isInterrupted()` проверяет прерван ли поток. если вы хотите прервать  поток, то это метод `interrupt()`. мой вариант по сути тоже самое. но можно переделать и под `interrupt()`.

Comment: Извините что мучаю но не могли бы вы такой вариант тоже добавить а то боюсь задание вернут на переделку а дублировать вопрос нельзя. Или хотя-бы намекните как они друг друга заменяют...

Comment: у вас в задании, что-либо  есть про `interrupt()`?

Comment: А у меня метод .newScheduledThreadPool() требует int corePoolSize в качестве параметра так не компелируется

Comment: Да есть написано сделать так :Предусмотреть возможность останавливать вычисления, если время вычисления превышает 1 секунде. Для этого нужно реализовать проверку поведения isInterrunt()